# How to implement the reset function correctly?

Tags: python, pygame

My `reset()` function is supposed to clear everything and redraw the fresh ones, but it do not work. Can somehone give me some advice?

```
import pygame
import string
import random
import time
import sys

pygame.init ()
size = (1600, 900)
win = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption('Gerador de encontros para Tomb of Annihilation')
win.fill((255,255,255))
pygame.display.update()
red = (200,0,0)
green = (0,200,0)
blue = (0,0,200)
black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
encontro1 = "Aguardando"
encontro = 0
MONSTRO_T = "Arakrocra.jpg"
texto = "Monstro Puto"
item = "NONE"
image = pygame.image.load(MONSTRO_T)
imagePos = (1100,190)
win.blit(image, imagePos)
def text_objects(text, font, color):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, color)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()


def button(msg,x,y,w,h,ic,ac,it,at,action=None):
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()


    if x+w > mouse[0] > x and y+h > mouse[1] > y:
        pygame.draw.rect(win, ac,(x,y,w,h))
        smallText = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf",18)
        textSurf, textRect = text_objects(msg, smallText,at)
        textRect.center = ( (x+(w/2)), (y+(h/2)) )
        win.blit(textSurf, textRect)
        if click[0] == 1 and action != None:
            action()
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(win, ic,(x,y,w,h))
        smallText = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf",20)
        textSurf, textRect = text_objects(msg, smallText,it)
        textRect.center = ( (x+(w/2)), (y+(h/2)) )
        win.blit(textSurf, textRect)
## x = eixoX, y = eixoY, w = Altura, h = Largura, ic = Cor inativa ( do botão ), ac = cor ativa, it = Inative text color, at = active text color
def M_generator():
    return (random.randint(1,100))

def ef():
    global encontro
    global encontro1
    encontro = 1
    encontro1 = "Characters Level 1 to 4"


def en():
    global encontro
    global encontro1
    encontro = 2
    encontro1 = "Characters Level 4 to 8"


def em():
    global encontro
    global encontro1
    encontro = 3
    encontro1 = "Characters Level 8 or above"

def warning():
    largeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf',50)
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects('Selecione a dificuldade primeiro', largeText, red)
    TextRect.center = ((700),(300))
    win.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)
    pygame.display.update()

def lore(tf,color,ta,tl,texto):
    largeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf',tf)
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects(texto, largeText, color)
    TextRect.center = ((tl),(ta))
    win.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)
    pygame.display.update()

def quitgame():
    pygame.quit()
    exit()

def CACHES():
    global texto
    global item
    roll = (random.randint(1,20))
    if roll == 1:
        texto = "Rain catcher (see chapter l) and mess kit "
        item1 = (random.randint(1,100))
        item = "1"
    elif roll == 2:
        texto = "10-day supply of preserved rations"
        item1 = (random.randint(1,10))
        item = str(item1)
    elif roll == 3:
        texto = "20-day supply of preserved rations"
        item1 = (random.randint(1,20))
        item = str(item1)
    elif roll == 4:
        texto = "50-day supply of preserved rations"
        item1 = (random.randint(1,50))
        item = str(item1)
    elif roll == 5:
        texto = "ld4 casks of water holding 5 gallons each"
        item1 = (random.randint(1,4))
        item = str(item1)
    elif roll == 6:
        texto = "ld4 casks oftej (see chapter l)"
        item1 = (random.randint(1,4))
        item = str(item1)
    elif roll == 7:
        texto = "ld4 climber's kits"
        item1 = (random.randint(1,4))
        item = str(item1)
    elif roll == 8:
        texto = "20-day supply of insect repellent salve (see chapter l) in a leather tube"
        item1 = (random.randint(1,20))
        item = str(item1)
    elif roll == 9:
        texto = "ld4 quivers, each containing ld20 arrows"
        item1 = (random.randint(1,4))
        item = str(item1)
    elif roll == 10:
        texto = "Canoe with six paddles"
        item1 = (random.randint(1,100))
        item = "1"
    elif roll == 11:
        texto = "2 hooded lanterns and 10 flasks of lamp oil"
        item1 = (random.randint(1,10))
        item = str(item1)
    elif roll == 12:
        texto = "Two-person tent and ld4 explorer's packs"
        item1 = (random.randint(1,4))
        item = str(item1)
    elif roll == 13:
        texto = "Wooden box containing 2dl0 daggers (low quality,of the type used as trade goods)"
        item1 = (random.randint(2,20))
        item = str(item1)
    elif roll == 14:
        texto = "20-day supply of insect repellent salve (see chapter l) in a leather tube"
        item1 = (random.randint(1,20))
        item = str(item1)
    elif roll == 15:
        texto = "Set of navigator's tools"
        item1 = (random.randint(1,100))
        item = "1"
    elif roll == 16:
        texto = "ldlO changes of woolen clothing"
        item1 = (random.randint(1,10))
        item = str(item1)
    elif roll == 17:
        texto = "Set of cartographer's tools"
        item1 = (random.randint(1,100))
        item = "1"
    elif roll == 18:
        texto = "Two-person tent and 1d4 healer's kits"
        item1 = (random.randint(1,4))
        item = str(item1)
    elif roll == 19:
        texto = "2 two-person tents, folding camp table, and four folding stools"
        item1 = (random.randint(1,100))
        item = "1"
    else :
        texto = "Wooden box containing 2d4 po lions of healing"
        item1 = (random.randint(2,8))
        item = str(item1)



def beach():
    global MONSTRO_T
    MONSTRO_N = (M_generator())
    if (MONSTRO_N < 7):
        if encontro == 1:
            MONSTRO_T = "Arakocra.jpg"
            imagePos = (900,190)
            win.blit(image, imagePos)
            lore(30,black,250,500,"Any character with a passive Wisdom (Perception) score ")
            lore(30,black,300,500,"of 15 or higher spots ld4 + 1 aarakocra flying overhead. ")
            lore(30,black,350,500,"These creatures are scouts from Kir Sabal or another ")
            lore(30,black,400,500,"aerie. They observe the party from a safe distance")
            lore(30,black,450,500,"but don't approach unless the characters demonstrate")
            lore(30,black,500,500,"peaceful intentions. The bird folk are friendly and can")
            lore(30,black,550,500,"point characters in the direction of nearby landmarks.")
            grupo1 = (random.randint(1,4)+1)
            print(grupo1)
            grupo = str(grupo1)
            lore(35,black,600,500,"Grupo de ")
            lore(35,black,600,650,grupo)
        if encontro == 2:
            MONSTRO_T = "Arakocra.jpg"
            imagePos = (900,190)
            win.blit(image, imagePos)
            lore(30,black,250,500,"Any character with a passive Wisdom (Perception) score ")
            lore(30,black,300,500,"of 15 or higher spots 2d4 + 2 aarakocra flying overhead. ")
            lore(30,black,350,500,"These creatures are scouts from Kir Sabal or another ")
            lore(30,black,400,500,"aerie. They observe the party from a safe distance")
            lore(30,black,450,500,"but don't approach unless the characters demonstrate")
            lore(30,black,500,500,"peaceful intentions. The bird folk are friendly and can")
            lore(30,black,550,500,"point characters in the direction of nearby landmarks.")
            grupo1 = (random.randint(2,8)+2)
            print(grupo1)
            grupo = str(grupo1)
            lore(35,black,600,500,"Grupo de ")
            lore(35,black,600,650,grupo)
        if encontro == 3:
            MONSTRO_T = "Arakocra.jpg"
            imagePos = (900,190)
            win.blit(image, imagePos)
            lore(30,black,250,500,"Any character with a passive Wisdom (Perception) score ")
            lore(30,black,300,500,"of 15 or higher spots 3d4 + 3 aarakocra flying overhead. ")
            lore(30,black,350,500,"These creatures are scouts from Kir Sabal or another ")
            lore(30,black,400,500,"aerie. They observe the party from a safe distance")
            lore(30,black,450,500,"but don't approach unless the characters demonstrate")
            lore(30,black,500,500,"peaceful intentions. The bird folk are friendly and can")
            lore(30,black,550,500,"point characters in the direction of nearby landmarks.")
            grupo1 = (random.randint(3,12)+3)
            print(grupo1)
            grupo = str(grupo1)
            lore(35,black,600,500,"Grupo de ")
            lore(35,black,600,650,grupo)
    elif ((MONSTRO_N > 7) and (MONSTRO_N < 10)):
        MONSTRO_T = "Cache.jpg"
        imagePos = (900,190)
        win.blit(image, imagePos)
        lore(30,black,250,500,"The party finds a cache of supplies left behind by other")
        lore(30,black,300,500,"explorers. There's no way to ten from the cache whether")
        lore(30,black,350,500,"those who left it are still alive and coming back for it, or")
        lore(30,black,400,500,"dead. Roll a d20 and consult the Caches table to determine what")
        lore(30,black,450,500,"the characters find. ")
        lore(30,black,500,500,texto)
        lore(30,black,500,700,item)

    elif ((MONSTRO_N > 10) and (MONSTRO_N < 12)):
        MONSTRO_T = "Chwinga.jpg"
    elif ((MONSTRO_N > 12) and (MONSTRO_N < 14)):
        MONSTRO_T = "Dinossauro, Allosaurus.jpg"
    elif ((MONSTRO_N > 14) and (MONSTRO_N < 16)):
        MONSTRO_T = "Dinossauro, Dimetrodon.jpg"
    elif ((MONSTRO_N > 16) and (MONSTRO_N < 21)):
        MONSTRO_T = "Dinossauro, Plesiosaurus.jpg"
    elif ((MONSTRO_N > 21) and (MONSTRO_N < 28)):
        MONSTRO_T = "Dinossauro, Pteranodon.jpg"
    elif ((MONSTRO_N > 28) and (MONSTRO_N < 31)):
        MONSTRO_T = "Dinossauro, Quetzalcoatlus.jpg"
    elif ((MONSTRO_N > 31) and (MONSTRO_N < 37)):
        MONSTRO_T = "Dinossauro, Velociraptor.jpg"
    elif ((MONSTRO_N > 37) and (MONSTRO_N < 40)):
        MONSTRO_T = "Dragon, Red.jpg"
    elif ((MONSTRO_N > 40) and (MONSTRO_N < 42)):
        MONSTRO_T = "Emerald Enclave.jpg"
    elif ((MONSTRO_N > 42) and (MONSTRO_N < 46)):
        MONSTRO_T = "Explorers.jpg"
    elif ((MONSTRO_N > 46) and (MONSTRO_N < 49)):
        MONSTRO_T = "Flaming Fist.jpg"
    elif ((MONSTRO_N > 49) and (MONSTRO_N < 52)):
        MONSTRO_T = "Flying Monkeys"
    elif ((MONSTRO_N > 52) and (MONSTRO_N < 55)):
        MONSTRO_T = "Flying Snakes.jpg"
    elif ((MONSTRO_N > 55) and (MONSTRO_N < 57)):
        MONSTRO_T = "Frost Giants"
    elif ((MONSTRO_N > 57) and (MONSTRO_N < 63)):
        MONSTRO_T = "Giant Lizard"
    elif ((MONSTRO_N > 63) and (MONSTRO_N < 67)):
        MONSTRO_T = "Giant Snapping Turtle"
    elif ((MONSTRO_N > 67) and (MONSTRO_N < 71)):
        MONSTRO_T = "LizardFolk"
    elif ((MONSTRO_N > 71) and (MONSTRO_N < 74)):
        MONSTRO_T = "Red Wizard"
    elif ((MONSTRO_N > 74) and (MONSTRO_N < 84)):
        MONSTRO_T = "Sea Hags"
    elif ((MONSTRO_N > 84) and (MONSTRO_N < 87)):
        MONSTRO_T = "Stirges"
    elif ((MONSTRO_N > 87) and (MONSTRO_N < 89)):
        MONSTRO_T = "Swarm of bats"
    elif ((MONSTRO_N > 89) and (MONSTRO_N < 94)):
        MONSTRO_T = "Tabaxy Hunter"
    elif ((MONSTRO_N > 94) and (MONSTRO_N < 100)):
        MONSTRO_T = "Tri-Flower Frond"

def noundead():
    print("oioioi")

def Lundead():
    print("oioioi")

def Gundead():
    print("oioioi")

def mountains():
    print("oioioi")

def rivers():
    print("oioioi")

def ruins():
    print("oioioi")

def swamp():
    print("oioioi")

def wasteland():
    print("oioioi")

def reset():
    win.fill(white)
    button("Facil",20,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,ef)
    button("Normal",150,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,en)
    button("Mortal",280,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,em)
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
    main()



def main():
    while True:
        for ev in pygame.event.get():
            if ev.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                exit()
        button("Facil",20,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,ef)
        button("Normal",150,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,en)
        button("Mortal",280,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,em)
        button("reset",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)

        if encontro == 0:
            button("Aguardando",930,10,300,50,green,blue,black,white)
        elif encontro == 1:
            button("Characters Level 1 to 4",930,10,300,50,green,blue,black,white)
        elif encontro == 2:
            button("Characters Level 4 to 8",930,10,300,50,green,blue,black,white)
        elif encontro == 3:
            button("Characters Level 8 or above",930,10,300,50,green,blue,black,white)

        if  encontro == 0:
            button("Beach",20,100,110,50,green,blue,black,white,warning)
            button("NoUndead",150,100,110,50,green,blue,black,white,warning)
            button("- Undead",280,100,110,50,green,blue,black,white,warning)
            button("+ undead",410,100,110,50,green,blue,black,white,warning)
            button("Mountains",540,100,110,50,green,blue,black,white,warning)
            button("Rivers",670,100,110,50,green,blue,black,white,warning)
            button("Ruins",800,100,110,50,green,blue,black,white,warning)
            button("Swamp",930,100,110,50,green,blue,black,white,warning)
            button("Wasteland",1060,100,110,50,green,blue,black,white,warning)
            button("Sair",1060,100,110,50,green,blue,black,white,quitgame)
        elif encontro > 0:
            win.fill(white)
            if encontro == 1:
                button("Characters Level 1 to 4",930,10,300,50,green,blue,black,white)
            elif encontro == 2:
                button("Characters Level 4 to 8",930,10,300,50,green,blue,black,white)
            elif encontro == 3:
                button("Characters Level 8 or above",930,10,300,50,green,blue,black,white)
            button("Facil",20,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,ef)
            button("Normal",150,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,en)
            button("Mortal",280,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,em)

            button("Beach",20,100,110,50,green,blue,black,white,beach)
            button("NoUndead",150,100,110,50,green,blue,black,white,noundead)
            button("- Undead",280,100,110,50,green,blue,black,white,Lundead)
            button("+ undead",410,100,110,50,green,blue,black,white,Gundead)
            button("Mountains",540,100,110,50,green,blue,black,white,mountains)
            button("Rivers",670,100,110,50,green,blue,black,white,rivers)
            button("Ruins",800,100,110,50,green,blue,black,white,ruins)
            button("Swamp",930,100,110,50,green,blue,black,white,swamp)
            button("Wasteland",1060,100,110,50,green,blue,black,white,wasteland)
            button("Sair",1060,100,110,50,green,blue,black,white,quitgame)


        pygame.display.update()

main()
```

But when I use the `reset()` function, a loop crash the app.
What is wrong with my function?
I try use a lot of things, but I think my logic is wrong.
how I make a a `reset()` function to clear the app, and redraw everthing?
or, how to run from the start again?

Answer (score 2):

In general, a good Stack Overflow question would have all of the following:

- Enough of the code in question to recreate the problem. *You've given us that!*
- A clear description of how you *want* the code to behave. You've explained a little bit that you want the "reset" button to clear and redraw, which is probably clear enough for today.
- A clear description of how the code *actually* behaves. In this case, that would mean the exact error message.
- A discussion of what you've already tried to resolve the problem.

In this case, I think I've been able to recreate your problem. I added a couple print statements to help me see the flow, and ran your code. After printing out "reset" a bajillion times, I got this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 382, in <module>
    main()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 334, in main
    button("reset",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 319, in reset
    button("resete",410,10,110,50,green,blue,black,white,reset)
  File "SO_63564495.py", line 42, in button
    action()
[ELIDED because it is too damn long!]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/posixpath.py", line 153, in dirname
    sep = _get_sep(p)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/posixpath.py", line 42, in _get_sep
    if isinstance(path, bytes):
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

This tells us the problem: `reset()` is calling `button()`, which calls `reset()`, without limit until the program crashes. Probably something needs to happen inside `reset` so that `pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]` won't be `1` anymore inside of `button`; I'm not sure.

That said, it looks like you're a little over your head. There's a lot going on in your code that could be improved (made shorter, made easier to read, made easier to reason about and convince ourselves of the correctness of) if you started over using one-or-another programming abstraction to structure your work. [Object Oriented Programming](https://realpython.com/python3-object-oriented-programming/) is a good place to start.

You've taken on a big project; don't loose hope!

Comment: Shape Of Matter, thanks for tips. really, thanks
I started study python a couple of days, And I have a lot to learn.
you give me some good advices